# Given a thread id, how to decide it's still running or not on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

On linux, we have pthread_kill() to do this. I'm trying to find a Windows counterpart for it.

In other words, given a thread id, is there a way to decide whether the thread is still running or not?

GetExitCodeThread() is the closest I've found, however, it needs thread handle rather than thread id as its parameter.

Comment: I believe that `pthread_kill()` has the same drawbacks as described in your answers. Are you in control of the life of this thread, or is it just some random thread?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you mean we are still taking the risk resulting from id recycling on linux?

Comment: I don't believe you can portably use POSIX thread identifiers across process boundaries, so this caveat probably only applies to windows.

Comment: Yes I presume that is the case. I would expect both systems to take steps to make recycling collisions unlikely but it must be possible in both.

Comment: @Terry Where do the threads come from? Are they in your control?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think so. I have a data structure which keeps track of set of thread ids whose corresponding threads are ever created. I need to keep checking the status for each thread in the data structure, then I decide whether to delete them from it.

Comment: If you don't create them, who does?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My part is simply not aware of the creation or any other action of any thread. When a thread obtains a lock object, I just add the thread id to the owner list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use a thread id for this purpose:  thread ids can be reused, so if you get a thread id, then that thread exits, another thread can be started with that same thread id.

The handle does not have this problem:  once a thread terminates, all handles to that thread will reflect the terminated state of the thread.

You can obtain a handle for a thread with a given id using `OpenThread`; you can then pass that handle to `GetExitCodeThread` to determine whether the thread has exited.

Comment: I have just checked with my managers. They insist that not only the ids but the handles (essentially memory addresses) could be reused. So in their opinion it makes little difference to use one or the other. In practice, they conclude based on their twenty years experience that reuses of the same ids have been rarely observed.

Comment: Your managers are wrong:  if you open a handle to a thread, that handle will always refer to that thread, until you close the handle, even if the thread terminates.  Whether or not thread id reuse occurs frequently, it does not matter:  a correct program cannot assume that a particular thread id always refers to the same thread unless it has some other way of knowing (e.g., if you have a thread get its own id, it can know that that id is valid so long as it is running--thread ids won't change).

Answer (score 2):

In short, no, there isn't.  You can determine whether a thread with the given identifier exists or not.  However, you fundamentally can't determine that the thread you used to refer to using the given ID is still running or not.  That's because the thread ID will be recycled after the thread completes.

To track a thread's lifetime, you need to get a thread handle, which will allow you to keep the thread alive for as long as you need.  Think of it as a strong VS. weak reference thing.  You can use [`OpenThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to a thread given its ID.  You should do this ASAP after you get the ID, then always use the thread handle.

Comment: you mean ID gives us the handle, and in turn the handle gives us the running status? if so, we can get the running status from the ID.

Comment: Yes, but that is an unreliable method because you don't know for sure *which* thread's status you will be testing.  If the thread of interest finishes and all handles are closed, then any other process may create a thread that will possibly use that identifier.  If your test is performed after that, then you will get a false positive.

Comment: I have just checked with my managers. They insist that not only the ids but the handles (essentially memory addresses) could be reused. So in their opinion it makes little difference to use one or the other. In practice, they conclude based on their twenty years experience that reuses of the same ids have been rarely observed.

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng: Handles may be re-used, but no while you hold a reference to them.  Holding a thread ID gives no such promise.  Think of handles as a strong reference (keeps the object alive) and IDs as a weak reference (is implicitly invalidated if all strong references are released).  This is why I pointed out that you should get a handle ASAP and keep it alive until you don't need it any more.

Comment: As for the twenty years of experience thing, I have to warn you this is a poor argument.  Just because you haven't seen a bug creep up on you so far, that doesn't mean it isn't there.  Also, keeping IDs is valid if you can prove that the ID is kept for a shorter lifetime than the the thread itself.  This is possible to prove for some programs that only control their own threads.

Comment: What if the object is accidentally terminated? Then another object is created in the same location.

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng: for the handle to become available again, two things need to happen.  First, the thread function must complete (or crash).  Second, *all open handles to the thread* must be explicitly released using `CloseHandle()`.  If both those things happen, then another thread may be created with the same handle.